# Cross-site highlights have invalid URLs

Tags: bug, broken-link

Since recently, cross-site highlights (hot questions, Area 51 sites) have invalid links in the form of `https://stackoverflow.com/?url=X` that just open the Stack Overflow home page.

Examples:

[image]

Link: `https://stackoverflow.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhistory.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F40601%2Fdid-julius-caesar-say-africa-i-have-grabbed-you%3Futm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3Dhttps-stackoverflow-com-questionspage-5sort-newest%26utm_campaign%3Dhistory.stackexchange.com-promo%26utm_content%3D40601`

(also note the `http` without `s`)

---

[image]

Link: `https://stackoverflow.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Farea51.stackexchange.com%2Fproposals%2F105590%2Fbeaver-builder%3Fcommit%3D1%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_source%3D%26utm_campaign%3D-area51-promo`

---

Still happens in 2019.

[image]

Link: `https://stackoverflow.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fastronomy.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F29122%2Fif-light-has-no-mass-why-is-it-affected-by-gravity`

Comment: Off-topic: Now I had to look up myself if Julius Caesar actually said that or not.

Comment: @g00glen00b don't leave us hanging. Did he?